# Magnet force vs gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

I'm currently at work and the question of differences over the strength of gravity vs the strength of magnetism. Hypothetically if the sun was a giant neodymium magnet what affect would that have on earth. Aside from the lack of sunlight etc.. If there was a sun sized magnet how far would that magnetic field reach vs the effects of gravity.

Comment: rather than try to imagine this, I'd suggest thinking about the size of a magnet that you need to counter the Earth's gravity

Comment: Yes I would say that's part of it. Ultimately it's the distance of the effects of both. I know the sun being a neodymium magnet would change its density which would inturn change its gravitation effects but what would  have a further reach into space?its magnetic field or its gravity.

Comment: Looking at the equations for a force of gravity compared to the equation a magnetic field the magnetic field is more sensitive to distance than the gravitational force. So, assuming the same mass of the magnet and the sun the gravitational field will have a longer reach than the magnetic field. I found the equation for the magnetic field here, [link](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=surface-fields-101).

Comment: The question is fundamentally flawed because magnetic fields are dipole and not monopole fields. One can make a one to one comparison between electrostatic fields and gravity and come out on top, but magnetism and gravitation are apples and oranges.

Comment: I understand that the question is flawed because gravity attracts in all directions and magnets attract in a dipolar direction. But I belive my question was answered by anyone. The gravitational field has a further reach than the magnetic field. In theory If we were orbiting a massive magnet the gravity would hold us at a  safe orbit from the magnetic pull of the object. Anything close enough that was attracted to the magnetic object would have been pulled inwards long ago. Anythought outside the magnetic field would just orbit. Is this correct?

Comment: I think that even a magnetic object in the magnetic field of this would be able to orbit if it had the right velocity to counteract the combined gravitational force and magnet force. The magnetic field of the orbiting object would need to be free to move so that it can continually realign itself to the magnetic field of the large neodymium magnet. The orbit would probably look very strange if it is possible at all since the magnetic force would increase a lot if the object got closer to the large neodymium magnet.